# Let $z$ be a point in a metric space $(X, p)$. Why is $f: X\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=p(x,z)$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $z$ be a point in a metric space $(X, p)$. Why is $f: X\to\mathbb{R}$,  $f(x)=p(x,z)$ uniformly continuous?

I could draw a picture that illustrates the idea, please help me with the proof.

Comment: The triangle inequality.

Comment: @ArcticChar this is different. That post is a proof of continuity. Here i am asking about uniform continuity

Comment: @user1559897 And if you read the top answer, it explains explicitly how to prove uniform continuity. (And the question also asked for uniform continuity.)

Comment: @T.Bongers It wasnt, the uniform continuity in the question was added by me.

Comment: My mistake, sorry.